# I want to create a bank account transfer program. But stuck

Tags: java

I want to make a bank account transfer program. It's like one account transfers to another account and the amount change prints. I am doing this program between multiple accounts. So far, I wrote a method which accepts the amount to be transfer, account where to be transfer and account from where transfers; as parameters. I supply in main() to set values for these amount, account1(to transfer), account(from transfer). The exception coming is in Main() I am passing account1 and account2 where in the method it is only Account, I don't now how to write a Account class which accepts any account and less code. Can anyone write me a working code for this?

My code snippet is ,

```
public class BankHandler {
    public void transfer(int amount, Account debit, Account credit) {

    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        BankHandler bank = new BankHandler();

        Account1 acc1 = new Account1(); //I don't understand how to make multiple accounts to pass. The method transfer() accepts Account type classes only.
        Account2 acc2 = new Account2();
        Account3 acc3 = new Account3();

        bank.transfer(1000, acc1, acc2);
        bank.transfer(2000, acc3, acc2);
        bank.transfer(3000, acc1, acc3);
    }
}
```

I am a beginner.

Comment: Use a common `Account` interface, which all three classes implement.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no classes `Account1`, or `Account2`, or `Account3`. There is only a single class `Account`.

To make three `Account` class *instances*, do this

```
Account acc1 = new Account();
Account acc2 = new Account();
Account acc3 = new Account();
```

Comment: Ok, My target is to deduct an amount from one account and add in other account. What should I pass in Account() constructor?

Comment: @SharmisthaSakar You will need to define some methods in your `Account` class to deposit or withdraw into the account.  Maybe the initial balance should be passed in in the constructor, or maybe the initial balance can be set up with a deposit method.  In any case, StackOverflow is not a site where we provide tutorials for beginners, and it's not a site where we "write you a working code".  I think that this is as much as we can give you, and you'll need to get a Java book for beginners and work through it, or look for a Java tutorial online.

Answer (score 0):

Ha ha  I made this code work,

```
    package threadDemo;

    class Account {

private int balance;

// constructor
public Account(int initBalance) {
    // need to ensure that the initial balance is NOT negative
    if(initBalance < 0) {
        initBalance = 0;
    }

    balance = initBalance;
}

// to deposit amount
public int deposit(int amount) {
    balance = balance + amount;
    return balance;
}

// to withdraw amount
public int withdraw(int amount) {
    balance = balance - amount;
    return balance;

}

// returns the balance of the account
public int getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

// sets a new value to balance
public void setBalance(int bal) {
    // to ensure we don't set negative balance
    if(bal < 0) {
        bal = 0;
    }
    balance = bal;
}

    }

    public class BankHandler {
public void transfer(int amount, Account debit, Account credit) {
    debit.withdraw(amount); // removes amount from debit account
    credit.deposit(amount); // adds amount to credit amount
}

public static void main(String a[]) {
    BankHandler bank = new BankHandler();

    // All the bank accounts have been initialized with 5000
    Account acc1 = new Account(5000);
    Account acc2 = new Account(5000);
    Account acc3 = new Account(5000);

    bank.transfer(1000, acc1, acc2);
    bank.transfer(2000, acc3, acc2);
    bank.transfer(3000, acc1, acc3);

    System.out.println("Balance in Account 1 "+acc1.getBalance());
    System.out.println("Balance in Account 2 "+acc2.getBalance());
    System.out.println("Balance in Account 3 "+acc3.getBalance());


    }
    }
```